# Adding "Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" to my project creates new errors

Tags: vb.net

Sort of a newbie here - retired VB programmer, so I am a newbie in VB.Net.

I have been developing a program, and in testing functions, I have been reading text from a file.  I am ready to go to my next step of getting my data from an Excel file rather than a text file.  So I add the following line:
"Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"

And now previously existing code has broken.  The last line in this group now errors

`"Reference to a non-shared member required an object reference":`

```
  Using G = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp)
  'Paint the canvas 
  G.Clear(Color.Black)
  G.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear
  G.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
  G.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel
```

And

```
Dim F As New Font(Font_name, Font_Size)
```

now gives an error "'New' cannot be used on an interface"

And

```
Dim allFonts As New Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection
```

errors with "'Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection' is not defined"

AND...  Most mysteriously,
If FontDialog1.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
errors with "'Forms' is not a member of 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Windows'"

And all I did was add "Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" to the top of my form.  The program was running with no errors before then.

Any pointers to what the heck is going on would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you also add a *reference* to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ?

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right track to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add a *Reference* to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as well as using an Imports statement

Comment: That fixed it - thanks.  What confuses me is why would *adding* a reference break already referenced objects?

Comment: That is too broad a question to answer properly I'm afraid. It could be any number of things and it's impossible to say without a lot more information.